# Combine two expression in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

What is the correct ways to merge or combine  2 expression

`=iif(Fields!XXX.Value="Department",56,0)or iif(Fields!YYY.Value="Company",56,0)`...

try soo many ways but  got an error until i got this,is there any other ways to write this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=iif(Fields!XXX.Value="Department" or Fields!YYY.Value="Company", 56, 0)
```